# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Homebrewing Stack Exchange](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Force Carbonating and Serving Kegs Simulanteously](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14578/force-carbonating-and-serving-kegs-simulanteously)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Looking for a WARM ginger beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14635/looking-for-a-warm-ginger-beer)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Measuring SG on small (3.5l / 1g) batches](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14672/measuring-sg-on-small-3-5l-1g-batches)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Yeast nutrients](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14688/yeast-nutrients)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Adding yeast at the end of a long fermentation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14622/adding-yeast-at-the-end-of-a-long-fermentation)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Should I be worried about my bottles exploding?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/should-i-be-worried-about-my-bottles-exploding)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Brew stand recommendations](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14687/brew-stand-recommendations)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [On using a stainless steel tea bag to hold the hops while boiling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/on-using-a-stainless-steel-tea-bag-to-hold-the-hops-while-boiling)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How long does a white labs liquid yeast vial last once opened?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14690/how-long-does-a-white-labs-liquid-yeast-vial-last-once-opened)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What can have caused my mead to have the taste of yeast?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/14707/what-can-have-caused-my-mead-to-have-the-taste-of-yeast)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---